# Calculate neighbor values in array

Tags: python, average, neighbours

Given a list of tuples, `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2) ... (xm, ym)]` such as `[(1, 2), (3, 7), (5, 9)]` I would like to write a function that fills in the missing integer values x with the average of the neighbor values f(x - 1), f(x + 1).

In this case, we would get:

`[(1, 2), (2, ave(2, 7)), (3, 7), (4, ave(7, 9)), (5, 9)]`

```
import numpy as np

# calculating nearest neighbor averages
def nearest(x, y):

# define the min and max for our line
min = np.amin(x)
max = np.amax(x)

# fill in the gaps
numsteps = max - min + 1

# an empty vessel 
new_df = []

# an empty vessel for our xs
xs = np.linspace(min, max, numsteps)

for i, item in enumerate(xs):
    if(xs[i] in x):
        idx = x.index(xs[i])
        new_df.insert(i, (xs[i], y[idx]))
    else:
        idx = x.index(xs[i] - 1)
        idx2 = x.index(xs[i] + 1)
        avg = (y[idx] + y[idx2])/2.0
        new_df.insert(i, (xs[i], avg))

print new_df


nearest([1, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8])

// [(1.0, 6), (2.0, 6.5), (3.0, 7), (4.0, 7.5), (5.0, 8)]
```

This quickly fails, however, with an array such as `xs = [1, 4, 7]`, since the values are more than one away from each other. In that case, given the same `ys = [2, 7, 9]`, we would expect the answer to either be:

`[(1, 2), (2, ave(2, 7)), (3, ave(2,7)), (4, 7) ... ]`

or

Something a bit more complicated:

`[(1, 2), (2, ave(prev, next_that_exists)), (3, ave(just_created, next_that exists), ...]`

How can I implement so that we find the elements just below the missing one and just above the missing one, and compute their average?

Also, is this different from a moving average?

Comment: Your indentation is not correct. Please help us by fixing it.

Comment: If xs = [1, 4, 7] what do you want the answer to be?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Comment: This is actually pretty interesting. In the case of a gap of 2, you basically have `2, a, b, 7` where `a = (2 + b)/2` and `b = (a+7)/2` - two equations with two unknowns. With a gap of 3 you have `2, a, b, c, 7`, with `a = (2+b)/2`, etc... - three equations with three unknowns. I'm trying to come up with an elegant way to solve this, but nothing yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach: from the input, create a dictionary with the first list as the key and the second list as value. Then create a function, `get_value()` to get the value, calculate it if needed.

```
def get_value(pairs, key):
    try:
        return pairs[key]
    except KeyError:
        previous_value = get_value(pairs, key -1)
        next_value = get_value(pairs, key + 1)
        return (previous_value + next_value) / 2.0

def nearest(x, y):
    pairs = dict(zip(x, y))
    for i in range(1, max(x) + 1):
        yield i, get_value(pairs, i)

print list(nearest([1, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8]))
```

## Update

I now have a chance to revisit this question. Based on your description, you want to interpolate the missing values. Since you already have `numpy` installed, why not use it?

```
import numpy as np

def nearest(x, y):
    all_x = range(min(x), max(x) + 1)
    return zip(all_x, np.interp(all_x, x, y))

print nearest([1, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8])
print nearest([1, 4, 7], [6, 7, 8])
```

Output:

```
[(1, 6.0), (2, 6.5), (3, 7.0), (4, 7.5), (5, 8.0)]
[(1, 6.0), (2, 6.333333333333333), (3, 6.666666666666667), (4, 7.0), (5, 7.333333333333333), (6, 7.666666666666667), (7, 8.0)]
```

The `numpy.interp` does all the heavy lifting, function nearest only need to figure out a list of all the `x` values.

Comment: This gives an infinite loop on `nearest([1, 4, 7], [3, 4, 5])`

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. There is a gap between 1 and 4, and the original poster does not specify how to fill that gap. Now that the OP have posted an update in requirements. I am working on updating my solution.

Comment: He did underspecify it, but he was asking for code to specifically solve this case - it seems like his code already handles the non-gap cases.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def nearest(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)

    res = []
    for i in xrange(len(x)-1):
        res.append((x[i], y[i]))
        gap = x[i+1] - x[i]
        for j in xrange(1, gap):
            res.append((x[i]+j, y[i] + j * (y[i+1]-y[i]) / float(gap)))
    res.append((x[-1], y[-1]))

    return res
```

**Sample output**:

```
print nearest([1, 3, 5], [2, 7, 9])
print nearest([1, 4, 7], [2, 7, 9])
```

Gives:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 4.5), (3, 7), (4, 8.0), (5, 9)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3.666666666666667), (3, 5.333333333333334), (4, 7), (5, 7.666666666666667), (6, 8.333333333333334), (7, 9)]
```

**Explanation**:

I solved the `[1, 4]`, `[2, 7]` case by hand, noting that the values we want are `2, x, y, 7` where

```
x = (2 + y) / 2
y = (x + 7) / 2
```

I got `x = 11/3` and `y = 16/3`, yielding:

```
6/3, 11/3, 16/3, 21/3
```

Note that the gap between each of these is `5/3`, or `(7-2) / (4-1)`. That's when I realized that by wanting to fill in with the average of the neighbor values across larger gaps, you basically want a linear interpolation from one value to the next over the given number of steps. That is, for example, given you want to go from `2` to `7` in `3` steps, you add `5/3` to `2` repeatedly until you get to `7`.